# Loading value on drop down

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an edit form for my site. I have drop downs that let someone select a contact, but it never defaults to the value already in the database, just selects the first one in the list generated from the for loop.

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Client</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control input-large select2me input-sm" name="client"  value={{$job->client}}>
                            @foreach ($clients as $client)
                                <option value="{{ $client->id }}">{{$client->first_name}} {{$client->last_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Am I doing something wrong for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Client</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control input-large select2me input-sm" name="client">
                            @foreach ($clients as $client)
                              <!-- check the selected attribute -->
                                <option @if($client->id==$job->client) selected="selected" @endif value="{{ $client->id }}">{{$client->first_name}} {{$client->last_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

check the `selected` attribute above.